# Best use of function created in C++ from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

in .h file

```
void EXPORT_API GetModelReferences(int &nVertices, void * i_vertices, int &nTriangles, void* i_triangles, void * i_normals, void * i_uvCoordinates);
```

where `EXPORT_API`is a define of `#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)`

i created a dll that has one function:

```
GetModelReferences(int &nVertices, void * i_vertices, int &nTriangles, void* i_triangles, void * i_normals, void * i_uvCoordinates);
```

now i want to use it from `C#` code so this is how my `C#` looks like:

```
    [DllImport("LoadModelDll")]

//unsafe
public unsafe static extern void GetModelReferences(ref int nVertices, ref float[] vertices,ref int nTriangles,ref float[] triangles,ref float[] normals,ref float[] uvCoordinates);

//static extern void GetModelReferences(ref int nVertices, float* vertices, ref int nTriangles, IntPtr triangles, float*[] normals, float*[] uvCoordinates);



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh ();
    mf.mesh = mesh;

    unsafe {
        int lnVertices = 0;
        int lnTriangls = 0;


        float[] lVertices = new float[12];
        float[] lTriangles = new float[6];
        float[] lNormals = new float[12];
        float[] lUVcoordinates = new float[8];

        GetModelReferences(ref lnVertices,  ref lVertices ,ref lnTriangls,ref lTriangles,ref lNormals,ref lUVcoordinates);

    }
 }
```

the program crash when hits the line that calling the function.
i am new to C# programming and not sure about how to manage this.

```
CODE OF C++:


void GetModelReferences(int &nVertices, void * i_vertices, int &nTriangles, void* i_triangles, void * i_normals, void * i_uvCoordinates){

    float * vertices = (float*)i_vertices;
    int * triangles = (int*)i_triangles;
    float * normals = (float*)i_normals;
    float * uvCoordinates = (float*)i_uvCoordinates;

    //set uv coordinates
    int uvCoordinatesArray[8];

    uvCoordinatesArray[0] = 0;
    uvCoordinatesArray[1] = 0;

    uvCoordinatesArray[2] = 1;
    uvCoordinatesArray[3] = 0;

    uvCoordinatesArray[4] = 0;
    uvCoordinatesArray[5] = 1;

    uvCoordinatesArray[6] = 1;
    uvCoordinatesArray[7] = 1;

    //set normals
    int normalsArray[12];
    normalsArray[0] = 0;
    normalsArray[1] = 0;
    normalsArray[2] = 1;

    normalsArray[3] = 0;
    normalsArray[4] = 0;
    normalsArray[5] = 1;

    normalsArray[6] = 0;
    normalsArray[7] = 0;
    normalsArray[8] = 1;

    normalsArray[9]  = 0;
    normalsArray[10] = 0;
    normalsArray[11] = 1;

    memcpy(normals, &normalsArray, sizeof(int) * 12);

    //set nTriangles
    int numberOfTringles = 6;
    nTriangles = numberOfTringles;


    //set nVertices parameter
    int numberOfVertices = 12;
    nVertices = numberOfVertices;



    //set vertices parameter
    float width = 350;
    float height = 50;
    float verticesArray[12];

    verticesArray[0] = 0;
    verticesArray[1] = 0;
    verticesArray[2] = 0;

    verticesArray[3] = width;
    verticesArray[4] = 0;
    verticesArray[5] = 0;

    verticesArray[6] = 0;
    verticesArray[7] = height;
    verticesArray[8] = 0;

    verticesArray[9] = width;
    verticesArray[10] = height;
    verticesArray[11] = 0;

    memcpy(vertices, &verticesArray, sizeof(float)*4*3);


    // setting triangle values.
    int tri[6];

    tri[0] = 0;
    tri[1] = 2;
    tri[2] = 1;
    tri[3] = 2;
    tri[4] = 3;
    tri[5] = 1;

    memcpy(triangles, &tri, sizeof(float)* 6);
}
```

Comment: There are two problems here that I can see. The first of which is that your C++ function is probably getting its name mangled, and secondly its calling convention doesn't match your p/invoke signature.

Comment: Start by changing your C++ function to be `extern "C"` to stop the names from getting mangled, and set your DllImport to use Cdecl calling convention.

Comment: sorry, it is already declared like so, changes added in edit

Comment: when i copy the signature from the c++ to c# i get errors, how can i make it similar?

Comment: It is a hopeless function declaration, using `void*` as an argument type doesn't give anybody a clue how to properly use the function.  It doesn't even look like C++ code.  Remove `ref` from the array arguments, perhaps.  You need to find the C++ programmer and ask him, no need to be particularly friendly about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your declaration(s) in the C++ DLL in an extern "C" scope like so

```
extern "C"
{
    void __declspec(dllexport) GetModelReferences(int &nVertices, void * i_vertices, int &nTriangles, void* i_triangles, void * i_normals, void * i_uvCoordinates);
}
```

Then in your C# code specify the calling convention in your DllImportAttribute e.g.

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
namespace UseCppDll
{
    struct Program
    {
        [DllImport("LoadModelDll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public unsafe static extern void GetModelReferences(ref int nVertices, float* vertices,ref int nTriangles, float* triangles, float* normals, float* uvCoordinates);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            unsafe {
                int lnVertices = 0;
                int lnTriangls = 0;


                float* lVertices = stackalloc float[12];
                float* lTriangles = stackalloc float[6];
                float* lNormals = stackalloc float[12];
                float* lUVcoordinates = stackalloc float[8];

                GetModelReferences( ref lnVertices,  lVertices , ref lnTriangls, lTriangles, lNormals, lUVcoordinates);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it has reduce the errors but now i am not sure why is it crashing, i will ad my c++ code to the question

Comment: Tried that C++ code and it works fine in my build - x86 C++ Dll and x86 C# application. Is the c# code successfully loading the DLL?

Comment: i have debugged the code and it crash here:  memcpy(normals, &normalsArray, sizeof(int) * 12);

Comment: My mistake. I was using the old Dll.

Comment: C# code updated. Should at least not crash now. However, the C++ implementation of GetModelReferences() has some bugs e.g. triangles are floats in c# but are ints in C++. Also normals are floats in both but memcpy is using sizeof(int) when copying an array of normals.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the "fixed" keyword if you don't want to use stackalloc to create the arrays in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "PInvoke Interop Assistant" tool to create compatible C# signature for given native method.

You can find it in the following link.
http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120

Please make sure you consciously use calling conventions ( CDECL or STDCALL) when you export the function via the DLL

When you didn't use relevant Calling conventions, the stack will become unbalance.

When you allocate memory for unmanaged code to use, use Marshal class to allocate memory.
It has function such as AllocHGlobal to allocate memory which need as a sequential memory chunk.

It better to use Intptr as C# parameters as well.